# How to install a MyGet package?

Tags: .net, nuget, myget

A quote from [ImageProcessor](https://github.com/JimBobSquarePants/ImageProcessor) repo

> We already have a [MyGet package repository](https://www.myget.org/F/imageprocessor/api/v3/index.json) - for bleeding-edge /
>   development NuGet releases.

The link points to some json file.

I used to install NuGet packages by id. What should I do with json?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you are using Visual Studio you will need to open the Package Manager Settings and create a new package source with the MyGet url. There are two URLs, one if you are using NuGet 2, which is for Visual Studio 2013 and older, or another url for Visual Studio 2015 and NuGet 3.

- NuGet v3 Feed url: https://www.myget.org/F/imageprocessor/api/v3/index.json
- NuGet v2 Feed url: https://www.myget.org/F/imageprocessor/

Note that you can use the NuGet v2 url in Visual Studio 2015, it still works there.

From the Tools menu, select NuGet Package Manager, Package Manager Settings. Select Package Sources. Then click the plus button to add a new package source. Give it a name and use one of the above feed urls.

Then open the NuGet package manager itself and select the new package source you added. Note that you will need Include prerelease checked to see any NuGet packages for the image processor feed.

If you are using MonoDevelop or Xamarin Studio then use the NuGet v2 Feed url.

Comment: "Then open the NuGet package manager itself " You mean, package manager console? Or does it have some other interface?

Comment: I see. Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Manage NuGet Packages for Solution in VS 2015

Comment: This is not the answer at al... The question was how to install **MyGet** packages, not NuGet packages.

Comment: @kipusoep - MyGet hosts NuGet packages. The original question is about how to install the NuGet packages from the ImageProcessor MyGet feed.